# Enable Kerberos on CE Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, omniauth, kerberos, gitlab-ce

Have anyone established to install and enable kerberos for Gitlab CE? 

I know that is only for EE but I believe that it is possible to be installed for CE also. There isn't any article or guide to help anyone with that.

Already tried to follow up this [guide](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Custom-omniauth-provider-configurations/815405208019432c5f7df244a96ec9d2eed52955#working-kerberos-configuration)

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev build-essential libkrb5-dev
sudo gem install omniauth-kerberos -v 0.2.0
#enable kerberos as it says here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/kerberos.html#http-git-access
```

but I cannot see the kerberos login option.

before 8.14.0 you can enable kerberos from just the guide for the Enterprise Edition but the callback isn't working.
on 8.14.0 the option isn't showing at all.

Answer (score 0):

[It isn't officially supported](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/427), but the backend authentication provider is omniauth, so it might still work.

There is at least one record of it working: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2510

You can try using the [old documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/a9f922096c48f0c5da92cf2d9c1749c6ed62c1cc/doc/integration/kerberos.md) for it

It might work, it might not. If you really need the feature, it's probably a good idea to pay for it :)

Comment: We are just a small group of programmers so We cannot afford to buy it. The problem is that LDAP needs plain text for the password that we don't like so I am trying to use the kerberos option. If I cannot make it work I will just use a whitelist of mails

Comment: plain text where exactly? you can configure ldap over SSL so the credentials aren't transmitted in plain text..

Comment: if you check the documentation for LDAP you will see that you have to add the password in the /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb file and they dodn't think that this is an issue

Comment: Ah I see, yes. If you create a limited access LDAP account, with only bind access, it should limit the security issues. It only needs permission to do LDAP lookups, so the scope of attack should be limited. I think this warrants a new question though, the original question is a different scope.

Comment: yes you are right, so lets focus on kerberos for now. i have already tried the old guide but nothing, thanks anyway